# A .jar file does not run after building it

Tags: jar, executable-jar

Actually, I'm trying to add new language to [Streama](https://github.com/streamaserver/streama) Media Server. I downloaded source code, added new language file (as guided [here](https://github.com/streamaserver/streama/wiki/Translating-the-app)). After that, I want to build a jar with that project, I build it with IntelliJ Idea 2021.1 ([here is how I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR85w.gif)). So, When I run that jar file (in Ubunt 20.04), it fails and gives this error: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAE7A.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

When you have made adjustments to the source code, it is likely that you will want to create a new .jar file and deploy it on your server. For this, you can use a simple command:

```
# for unix based systems
**./gradlew assemble** 

# for windows
**./gradlew.bat assemble**
```

This will create 2 new .jar files under **build/libs,**

- streama-{version}.jar
- streama-{version}.jar.original

**all you will need is the streama-{version}.jar.**

This file is an executable, so you can just copy it into your deployment directory / your server and start it as usual.